# Remove items of the array before the current year

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing some dates in following format. I want to remove the items with key before 2019 year.

This is the code I have tried so far. But I am not getting any result.

Can anybody please help me.

```
$array = [
  "date_2018_08" => 81,
  "date_2018_09" => 70,
  "date_2018_10" => 70,
  "date_2018_11" => 95,
  "date_2018_12" => 75,
  "date_2019_01" => 91,
  "date_2019_02" => 78,
  "date_2019_03" => 95,
  "date_2019_04" => 68
];
$year = 2019;
$month = 4;


$array = array_filter($array,function($date){
    $t1 = strtotime(str_replace(["date_", "_"], ["", "-"], $date));
    return $t1 >= strtotime(str_replace(["date_", "_"], ["", "-"], '2019-01-01'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` ([doc](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)) with flag "ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY" as:

```
$year = 2019;
$filtered = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($key) use ($year) {
        $parts = explode("_", $key);
        return $parts[1] >= $year;
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/7djaj)

**Edited:**

Using simple `foreach`:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $parts = explode("_", $k);
    if ($parts[1] >= $year)
        $filtered[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY

Comment: @SS Yes - simple foreach loop - Edited my post with how to do that

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo link**](https://3v4l.org/hOUpG).

You can pass $year and $month to filter out the array,

```
$year  = 2019;
$month = str_pad(4,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); // pad to left with zero to match string
$temp  = array_filter($array, function ($key) use ($year, $month) {
    return (strpos($key, $year . "_" . $month) === false);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
print_r($temp);die;
```

[strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string
[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function
[str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) — Pad a string to a certain length with another string

> Note: ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY - pass key as the only argument to callback
>   instead of the value